# Как проверить в объекте JSON наличие опредленного поля? JS

Tags: javascript, json

Как проверить при ответе в объекте JSON наличие определенного поля?
Например, получаю ответ в JSON:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name 'NAME',
    age: 30
}
```

но `age` может не всегда содержаться в объекте JSON. 
Например, содержится ли `age` в ответе или нет?

Comment: Ну, десериализируйте в объект, и используйте `hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: А просто проверка вида `if (result.age) {}` вас не устраивает? Можно и просто `'undefined' == typeof result.age`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var resp = '{"id": 1, "name": "NAME", "age": 30}';
var data = JSON.parse(resp);

if(typeof data.age === 'undefined')
  alert('Поля "age" нет');
else
  alert('Поле "age" в наличии, значение: ' + data.age);
```

Comment: При такой проверке значение поля `undefined` не отличимо от отсутствия поля

Comment: некрокомментарий: JSON.parse не может вернуть undefined в качестве значения поля

Answer (score 6):

Т.к. эта ситуация более-менне предусмотрена яваскриптом, лучше всего воспользоваться нативным методом:

```
var json = '{"id": 1, "name": "NAME", "age": 30}',
    data = JSON.parse(json);

if ('age' in data) {
    // branch a
} else {
    // branch b
}
```